# Better way of copying data?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables where I want to **copy the `post_id` from one table to another** when the `testpostmeta.meta_value = testTable.stockcode`

There's about **2000 rows** in `testTable` and **65k rows** in `testpostmeta`.

The code works, it just **takes about 1-2 minutes to complete**. Is there anything that can be done to speed the hamster wheel up?

```
UPDATE testTable 
  INNER JOIN testpostmeta 
    ON testTable.stockcode = testpostmeta.meta_value
   SET testTable.post_id = testpostmeta.post_id
```

I tried adding `WHERE testpostmeta.meta_value = testTable.stockcode` but that didn't work.

Comment: Does it matter? Surely you're only doing this once!?!

Comment: performed every 15 minutes or so to keep stock levels on website current with independent accounting system so a product(s) doesn't get sold that isn't in stock.

Answer (score 1):

be sure you have proper indexes  on testTable and testpostmeta

```
CREATE INDEX my_idx1  ON testTable (stokcode);

CREATE INDEX my_idx2  ON testpostmeta (meta_value , post_id);
```

Comment: I think the columns in reverse order - he compares meta_value , post_id is just to avoid table access

Comment: @cohenjo   correct answer  update .. (the where part must be at left)  ..

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an index to each table that matches the field used for your `JOIN` criteria:

```
ALTER TABLE testTable ADD INDEX stockcode_idx(stockcode);
ALTER TABLE testpostmeta ADD INDEX meta_idx(meta_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the autocommit

```
SET autocommit = 0 ;

--Insert/Update/Delete stuff here
COMMIT ;
```

Comment: It’s a single statement - there is only one commit here... it wouldn’t change anything

Comment: How many records it is updating/Inserting? If it is inserting 1000 records. Then Commit is executing 1000 times.

Comment: Doesn’t matter - it’s an atomic operation , you have a single commit.

Comment: Try once then let me know. I am suggesting this according to my past experience. That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

If `post_id` is indexed in target table that also can slow down the update.

Try disabling index before the operation and enable it after. So you data will be indexed once rather on each subsequent data change.

```sql
ALTER TABLE targetTable DISABLE KEYS;
-- Your UPDATE query
ALTER TABLE targetTable ENABLE KEYS;
```

And as said in the reference:

> Performing multiple updates together is much quicker than doing one at a time if you lock the table.

---

Here some reference page that can give more idea on what can be done:

- [8.2.4.2 Optimizing UPDATE Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update-optimization.html)
- [8.5.4 Bulk Data Loading for InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html)